# does slideToggle function of jquery behave differently with span and div?

Tags: jquery, dom

I am working on slideToggle function. if I use span tag to hide my content initially and on click of that span's parent I fire click event and call slide Toggle in it. The result of it is not proper.The span slides down and slides up immediately. But if I use div instead of span the slideToggle works properly.
Does any one knows why this kind of weird behavior with span?

Comment: Try setting up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to replicate the problem. I'll take a wild guess that it has nothing to do with jQuery, but that it's about CSS. A div is a block element, while a span is not, try setting the span to `display: block` in your CSS, and see if that does'nt fix it for you?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `span` have inline layout characteristics whereas `div` are layout in blocks. Behind the scenes, `span` elements have `display: inline` in their CSS declaration whereas `div` elements are styled with `display: block`. Practically speaking, if you place two `span` elements on your page with no styling, they'll appear next to each other whereas two `div` elements would appear beneath each other. More about CSS `display` property can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display).

`slideToggle` will animate the `width` property of the element and then toggle its `display` property between `none` and the original state. This doesn't work on inline elements, since the `width` property doesn't apply to their styling. Try it yourself!

```
#test {
    display: inline; // Try switching this to block
    width: 100px; // This only works for block elements
    background: red; // Make the change visible
}
```

So really, there's nothing wrong with `span`, it's all about how styling is applied. If you want to give an inline element a width, you can use `display: inline-block`:

```
#test {
    display: inline-block; // Layout inline with other content as one block
    width: 100px; // This works!
    background: red;
}
```